# How i can document inner collection constraints in spring auto restdocs

Tags: spring-restdocs, spring-auto-restdocs

I'm trying to document inner constraint for Collections (NotBlank and Size) like:

```
@Valid    
private List<@NotBlank @Size(min = 1, max = 100) String> someAnotherUsefulInformationList;
```

Can I do it with built-in functionality?

PS: I found a place where constraints resolved [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/restdocs/constraints/ValidatorConstraintResolver.java#L64) and after modifying this method I got access to needed constraints, but NotBlank fall into Optional field in [the snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqhMd.png)

Comment: The `Optional = false` in your snippet refers to the field `someAnotherUsefulInformationList` and the field itself is optional, i.e. there is no `@NotNull` annotation on it. I doubt that there is a way to get the inner constraints into the documentation with the built-in functionality.

Comment: I'm made custom solution, example [here](https://github.com/GrinRus/spring-auto-rest-docs-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in functionality does not provide documenting inner collections constraints.
After some research and finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822334/why-do-spring-resdocs-fielddescriptor-dont-gather-constraint-on-inner-objects) question i'm made a custom solution in this [repository](https://github.com/GrinRus/spring-auto-rest-docs-demo)